# Observables: Using an observable of boolean inside of another observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have the following code snippet:

```
bla$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return of(x && !(y && z);
}
```

where x and y are normal booleans and z is an `Observable<boolean>`. How can I make sure that the "inner" boolean is resolved correctly so I get the right return value from the method?

I already tried to use flatmap, but it didn't work :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Maybe this?

```js
function bla$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return z.pipe(
        map(zVal => x && !(y && zVal))
    );
}
```